# Remove whitespace from spacy doc.ents

Tags: spacy, spacy-3

I am trying to run a spacy model for NER. I have Doc object and doc.ents shows below output

```
(august 3, 2021, book building offer, bse, nse)
```

All the tags have space.Due to this i am receiving below error.

```
ValueError: [E024] Could not find an optimal move to supervise the parser. Usually, this means that the model can't be updated in a way that's valid and satisfies the correct annotations specified in the GoldParse. For example, are all labels added to the model? If you're training a named entity recognizer, also make sure that none of your annotated entity spans have leading or trailing whitespace or punctuation. You can also use the `debug data` command to validate your JSON-formatted training data
```

Can anyone suggest how to remove this whitespace?

Comment: Your entity output looks normal, I don't know what you mean by "all the tags have space". Have you tried checking the output of `spacy debug data`?

Answer (score 1):

Found out a problem in rule based labeling, the entity spans had leading or trailing whitespace.

To solve above problem, you can use below function:

```
def trim_entity_spans(data: list) -> list:
    """Removes leading and trailing white spaces from entity spans.

    Args:
        data (list): The data to be cleaned in spaCy JSON format.

    Returns:
        list: The cleaned data.
    """
    invalid_span_tokens = re.compile(r'\s')

    cleaned_data = []
    for text, annotations in data:
        entities = annotations['entities']
        valid_entities = []
        for start, end, label in entities:
            valid_start = start
            valid_end = end
            while valid_start < len(text) and invalid_span_tokens.match(
                    text[valid_start]):
                valid_start += 1
            while valid_end > 1 and invalid_span_tokens.match(
                    text[valid_end - 1]):
                valid_end -= 1
            valid_entities.append([valid_start, valid_end, label])
        cleaned_data.append([text, {'entities': valid_entities}])

    return cleaned_data
```

If you have documents labeled in new .spacy format then you can use below helper function:

```
new_docs = []
for doc in skweak.utils.docbin_reader("./ipo_v3.spacy",spacy_model_name='en_core_web_trf'):
    new_docs.append(doc)
```

Once you have all the docs, you can use them to convert into JSON format:

```
doc_examples = []
for i,j in enumerate(new_docs):
    spans_ex = [(ent.start_char,ent.end_char,ent.label_) for ent in new_docs[i].ents]
    doc_examples.append([new_docs[i].text,{"entities":spans_ex}])
```

Then you can simply use :

```
doc_examples = trim_entity_spans(doc_examples)
```